# CSS- how to make one component move to the left only if there are new components shown on the right

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Two components A and B.

A moves a little bit to the left only if there is B, Otherwise, A still keeps the original position.

The code is like:

```html
return (
 <div className="menu">
   <A className="comp-a" />
   { showB && <B className="comp-b" /> }
 <div>
);
```

I know one way is passing prop to A to change its style if shouldShowB == true.

But how to make A move automatically by only changing css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`

```
.menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

You then need to define when they should get next to each other - That works if you set both of there width from 100% to 50% or smth lower than 50% so that both would fit in the 100%.

I normally do that with this code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0) {
  .a {width: 100%}
  .b {width: 100%}
}
```

and then the other with where they should get next to each other:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .a {width: 50%}
  .b {width: 50%}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! flex-display does work!